# Will my dog remember his sister from 6 years?

Tags: dogs

I had found a post on facebook of a dog that looked exactly like my dog. I had friended her, and turned out that we had gotten our puppies from the same litter. We were hoping to meet up, and I was curious if the dogs would remember each other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible that they will.  You see it a lot in Mothers meeting their pups again after a long separation. I'm sure littermates would be similar. They might not go bonkers in that first moment, but after they smell eachother, they may be reminded of their earlier relationship.